# Foundation 6 - Using MotionUI Custom Mixins for Animate

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, css-animations, zurb-foundation-6, motionui

I've installed **Foundation 6 for Sites** using **SASS** and I'm compiling with **Gulp**. I'm trying to use the **Motion-UI** library for some animation effects, and I've got a lot of it working.

Working Demo of Pre-built Animations:
http://jsfiddle.net/4a9kux0r/7/

The problem I'm having is trying to use the **SASS** `mixins` available for the **Motion-UI** library to create custom effects.

I have the following in my Gulpfile in order to process it...

```
var PATHS = {
...
    sass: [
        'bower_components/foundation-sites/scss',
        'bower_components/motion-ui/src/'
    ],
...
};
```

So, with this in mind, the rest of my `.scss` files I'm using are set up into partials:

[image: File Hierarchy]

and my app.scss file...

```
@import 'settings';
@import 'foundation';
@import 'motion-ui';
...
@include motion-ui-transitions;
@include motion-ui-animations;
@import 'partials/base';
@import 'partials/typography';
@import 'partials/utilities';
@import 'partials/animations';
```

So, all said and done, an animation that is pre-built is working fine, such as:

`MotionUI.animateOut($('#foo'), 'fade-in');`

But if I try to make a custom mixin for it to combine effects, like this **SASS** I've placed into my `_animations.scss` partial

```
.combineAnimate {
  @include mui-animation(fade, spin, slide($direction: up, $amount: 120%));
}
```

Something like this isn't working...

`MotionUI.animateOut($('#foo'), 'combineAnimate');`

It's probably just something in where I'm defining the custom animation, or not importing something properly, etc. This is my first time using gulp and foundation 6 and I'm still trying to piece it all together, so any help is sincerely appreciated!

Docs: https://github.com/zurb/motion-ui/blob/master/docs/animations.md

---

It is only compiling into this css code:

```
.combineAnimate {
  -webkit-animation-name: custom-1;
          animation-name: custom-1; }

@-webkit-keyframes custom-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-1turn) translateY(120%);
            transform: rotate(-1turn) translateY(120%); }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0) translateY(0);
            transform: rotate(0) translateY(0); } }

@keyframes custom-1 {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-1turn) translateY(120%);
            transform: rotate(-1turn) translateY(120%); }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0) translateY(0);
            transform: rotate(0) translateY(0); } }
```

Comment: Added compiled code. And even with the transform, it isn't doing a whole lot of anything. The slide doesn't even appear to be compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the official documentation for Motion-UI plugin:

> "**Note that in order to play properly, the element must have at least the property animation-duration applied to it as well.**"

Being new to **CSS3 Animations**, I had ignored this very bold stated prerequisite. My **SASS** was compiling just fine.

```
@include motion-ui-transitions;
.combineAnimate {
  @include mui-animation(fade, spin, slide($direction: up, $amount: 120%));
  animate-duration: 2s;
}
```

Resolves the issue.